# Not sure how to turn a Java class into a C header and code

Tags: c, struct

I have the following java class:

```
class Rect {

    int width;
    int height;

    Rect (int a, int b){
        width = a;
        height = b;
    }

    int area() {
        return width * height;
    }
}
```

But I am not exactly sure how to turn it into a C code.

So far I have this:

**Header.h**

```
#pragma once
struct rect {
    int width, height;
};

int area();
```

**Header.c**

```
int area() {
//How do I access these?       
//return width * height;
}
```

**Main**

```
#include "Header.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct rect rect;

    rect.height = 5;
    rect.width = 10;

    //How do I call rect.area() in here?    
}
```

Comment: You are aware C is not an OOP language, aren't you?

Comment: Methods in Java have a hidden, implicit `this` parameter. In C, all parameters are explicit, so you have to make the parameter explicit, too.

Comment: "I would like the rect to be able to call this for itself" - that means you need a class, i.e. "C with classes", which would be something like C++, etc.

Comment: I am,  but the book that was given to me by university compares Java to C a lot, so I need to understand how to translate this class into C code

Comment: Sounds like it's not a very good book. What is it?

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on the basics of C. It's not a simple conversion, they are very programming languages with different philosophies

Comment: @RPGillespie When pretty much all modern languages are OOP based, it's very hard for someone who learned them first to go back to the old stuff like C

Comment: @Denki What do you think Java was written in? C powers every modern language (unless the developers decide to bootstrap a self-written compiler like Rust, but even then it was written in C).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in `C` but yes you can do emulate the thing with function pointer. Create a function pointer and then assign function `area` to it. (Maybe in some initilize function). But then also you have to do a lot of things to emulate it clearly.

For example there is no concept of `this` over here. So with every call you have to pass the address of the structure. So not sure how helpful this would be.

```
struct rect {
    int width, height;
    int (*f_area)(struct rect *);
};

int area(struct rect *p){
   return p->width*p->height;
}
```

---

```
/*
 This function dynamically allocates struct rect and returns
 its address
*/

   struct rect * get_rect(){
      ...
      rect->f_area = area;
      return rect;
   }
```

---

Call it like this

```
 int ar = rectvar->area(&rectvar);
```

---

But well now you may say that this is really stupid thing to do. But well `C` doesn't offer what you have asked for. So yes that's the thing.

This is how things become when you stretch a language to get the feature that there isn't. You can simply use the area function like this - saves you from some hardships of life.

```
struct rect rv;
rv.height = 10;
rv.width = 20;
int ar = area(&rv);
```

Comment: Pattern to call a method can be caught by some trick `#define CALL(o,m,a) o->m(o,a)`. varargs defines can also make the trick.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès.: Ye right. That is one way to go..but really I don't think that overall it is an overkill to try to use `C` to emulate these kind of things. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @coderec I disagree, you may benefit from specifying OO and implement it in C because you don't/can't have access to some OO language compiler.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès.: Ah ye that is true but why not use C++ here? Much more prominent. I admit what you said.

Answer (score 1):

```
int area(struct rect* r);

int area(struct rect* r) {
    return r->width * r->height;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct rect rect;

    rect.height = 5;
    rect.width = 10;

    printf("Area: %d\n", area(&rect));    
}
```

Basic C prefers to pass pointers. An OO language has an implicit parameter `this` to every method - so to say.

Typically the method would be marked with the "class:"

```
int rect_area(struct rect* r);
```

Answer (score 1):

With structure and functions over structures:

```
struct rect {
    int width, height;
};

struct rect *new_rect(int w,int h) {
    struct rect *this = malloc(sizeof struct rect); // should check bad alloc...
    this->width = w;
    this->height = h;
    return this;
}

int area(struct rect *this) { // in a method, 'this' can be viewed as an implicit parameter...
   return this->width*this->height;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct rect *rect = new_rect(5,10);
    area(rect);
    // beware of memory leaks, should add some destructor...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't provide a mechanism to call a function from an object and have it operate on that specific object's data (i.e., the implicit `this` pointer in Java and C++).  You must specify the object in the argument list of the function:

```
struct Rect {
  int width;
  int height;
};

int area( struct Rect r )       // struct keyword is necessary
{
  return r.width * r.height;
}

int main( void )
{
  struct Rect foo;              // struct keyword is necessary
  int a = area( foo );
  ...
}
```

In C, a `struct` tag name is not automatically a type name by itself - you'll have to use `struct Rect` to declare objects of that type.  If you want `Rect` to be a type name all by itself, you'll have to use the `typedef` facility:

```
typedef struct Rect Rect;
```

*Now* you can use `Rect` as a type name all by itself:

```
Rect foo;
```

This particular example passes the `struct Rect` object by value - the formal parameter `r` is a different object in memory from the actual parameter `foo`, and it receives a copy of `foo`'s contents.  This means any changes made to `r.width` or `r.height` in the function are not reflected in `foo`.

If your function needs to modify the contents of `foo`, then you'll need to pass a pointer to it:

```
void scale( struct Rect *r, int wscale, int hscale )
{
  r->width *= wscale;   // r->width equivalent to (*r).width
  r->heignt *= hscale;  // '->' implicitly dereferences pointer
}                       // before accessing member

int main( void )
{
  struct Rect foo = {10, 10}; // initialize width and height to 10
  ...
  scale( &foo, 2, 3 );
  ...
}
```

People will often pass `struct` types by pointer anyway, since creating a copy of a large `struct` type can be expensive.  If you pass a pointer to a function that *doesn't* need to modify the object, make sure to qualify it as `const`:

```
int area ( const struct Rect *r ) { return r->width * r->height; }
```

That way the compiler can yell at you if you accidentally try to write to
`width` or `height`.